# Find the max date to last one year transaction for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sum, ssms

I have to query in sql server where I have to find for each id it's volume such that we have last 1 year date for each id with it's volume.

for example below is my data ,

for each id I need to query the last 1 year transaction from when we have the entry for that id as you can see from the snippet for id 1 we have the latest date as 7/31/2020 so I need the **last 1 year** entry **from that date** for that id, **The highlighted one is exclude because that date is more than 1 year from the latest date for that id**

Similarly for Id 3 we have all the date range in one year from the latest date for that particular id

[image]

I tried using the below query and I can get the latest date for each id but I am not sure how to extract all the dates for each id from the latest date to one year, I would appreciate if some one could help me.

I am using Microsoft sql server would need the query which executes in sql server, Table name is **emp** **and have millions of id**

```
Select *
From emp as t
inner join (
    Select tm.id, max(tm.date_tran) as MaxDate
    From emp tm
    Group by tm.id
) tm on t.id = tm.id and t.date_tran = tm.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude transactions where the date difference between the tran_date and the maximum tran_date for each id is greater than 1 year, something like this:

```
;with max_cte(id, max_date) as (
    Select id, max(date_tran)
    From emp tm
    Group by id )
Select *
From emp e
     join max_cte mc on e.id=mc.id
                        and datediff(d, e.date_tran, mc.max_date)<=365;
```

Update: per comments, added volume.  Thnx GMB :)

```
;with max_cte(id, date_tran, volume, max_date) as (
    Select *, dateadd(year, -1, max(date_tran) over(partition by id)) max_date
    From #emp tm)
Select id, sum(volume) sum_volume
From max_cte mc
where mc.date_tran>max_date
group by id;
```

Comment: not  from current sys date but from the latest date for each id to the last 1 year date, if you see id no  1 the latest date is 7/31/2020  and from that date to last 1 year I need to extract and not from the current sys date

Comment: Sorry, read that wrong.  It's updated.  Now it uses the max_date for each id to return transaction less than or equal to 365 days prior

Comment: Remember though that functions cannot use indexes

Comment: @SteveC, Thnks so now based on the result extracted. if I just want the sum of vol with in 365 days  for each id what needs to be done, can you update that too in the query if possible

Comment: Updated, please review

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select id, sum(volume) total_volume
from (
    select t.*, max(date_tran) over(partition by id) max_date_tran
    from mytable t
) t
where date_tran > dateadd(year, -1, max_date_tran)
group by id
```

Alternatively, you can use a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select id, sum(volume) total_volume
from mytable t
where t.date_tran > (
    select dateadd(year, -1, max(t1.date_tran))
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id = t.id
)
```

The second query would take advantage of an index on `(id, date_tran)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. Just add the date difference function to get the particular time in between the transaction, like the following:

```
Select *
From emp as t
inner join ( Select id as id, max(date_tran) as maxdate
    From emp tm
    Group by id
) tm on t.id = tm.id and datediff(d, e.date_tran, mc.maxdate)<=365;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick for you:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    emp
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                MAX(date_tran) max_date_tran
                , Id
            FROM
                emp
            GROUP BY
                id
        ) emp2
        ON emp2.Id = emp.Id
           AND DATEADD(YEAR, -1, emp2.max_date_tran) <= emp.date_tran;
```